# scroll bar down while clicking on edit navigate to a section in a same page with angular

Tags: angular

I want to edit a section but that section is very bottom in a page when I click on edit button user doesn't understand where the edit section so I have used a simple with window.scrollTo(0, 1000);

Comment: Could you provide more details? Share the steps to reproduce what you already got or even a bit more of the code itself.

Comment: Having 3 sections in a component, one section is having the table list of some rows in that one column having edit pencil icon which is for the edit the row in other section in the same component. while clicking the pencil icon needs to navigate the page to the other section which having the all fields to edit.

Comment: You could use a ng-template for that. Then you open the row data in it as a dialog box and you can edit the data from there. I believe that is what you are looking for, correct? Let me know if I didn't understand it properly.

Comment: When I click on an Icon(Source) it has to scroll to another location(Destination) in angular 8 on the same page.